# Добавление TButton в TStringGrid

Tags: c++, c++builder

В пятый столбец на всех строках в контроле `StringGrid` нужно добавить кнопку, с возможностью взаимодействовать с ней. Во время решения столкнулся с проблемой что она `мерцает на StringGrid` и взаимодействия с ней нету, при наведении она никак не реагирует. По задумке это нужно для того чтобы получить более подробную информацию о человеке который есть в таблице `StringGrid`.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::StringGrid1DrawCell(TObject *Sender, int ACol, int ARow, TRect &Rect,
          TGridDrawState State)
{
    TButton *button = new TButton (Form1);

    if((ACol == 4) && (ARow > 0)) {
        button -> Parent = StringGrid1;
        button -> Left = Rect.Left;
        button -> Top = Rect.Top;
        button -> Width = 120;
        button -> Font -> Size = 8;
        button -> Caption = ("Получить информацию");
        button -> SetFocus();
    }
}
```

Можете подсказать как правильно и красиво это можно сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Нужно просто в каждый ряд контрола StringGrid добавить кнопки в пятую колонку и чтобы в дальнейшем можно было привязать к ней Event.